# Enable unofficial terminfo extensions in tmux

Tags: tmux

What must I do to make the escape sequence for double-underlining `\E[4:2m` work with tmux?

It works in my terminal (mintty) outside of tmux and I successfully adjusted my terminal's terminfo to account for [the terminfo extensions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#TERMINFO_EXTENSIONS) which tmux is compatible with to enable true-colors and overlining within tmux.

However, I cannot make the extended underlining feature work (the 'Smulx' codes). Here's my terminfo:

```
# Compile and add to database using 'tic -x <filename>'                      
#                                                                            
stanterm-256color|xterm with non-standard terminfo extensions,               
  use=xterm-256color,                                                        
  Tc,                                                                        
  Smol=\E[53m, Rmol=\E[55m,                                                  
# These underline extensions don't work in Tmux :(                           
# Smulx=\E[< WHAT GOES HERE? >m,  
# Smul2=\E[4:2m, does not work within tmux
```

My `.tmux.conf` only contains the minimal

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

I am running tmux 3.0 via byobu (tmux was built from source, as the overline-feature is very new). Any ideas?

Thanks

---

## Answer

### Option 1: Adjust tmux configuration

Add `set -as terminal-overrides ',*:Smulx=\E[4::%p1%dm'` to your `.tmux.conf` yielding

```
# .tmux.config
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -as terminal-overrides ',*:Smulx=\E[4::%p1%dm'

# ... rest of your configuration
```

### Option 2: Adjust terminfo

Append the corresponding termcap-string `Smulx=\E[4:%p1%dm,` to your terminfo *source* file and compile it using `tic -x <termfile>`. Note that contrary to the previous option the `Smulx` entry requires a single colon.

I chose the latter option. My terminfo source file looks like this:

```
# Compile and add to database using 'tic -x <filename>'
#
stanterm-256color|xterm with non-standard terminfo extensions,
  use=xterm-256color,
  Tc, 
  Smol=\E[53m, Rmol=\E[55m, 
  Smulx=\E[4:%p1%dm,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set -as terminal-overrides ',*:Smulx=\E[4::%p1%dm'

Comment: Can you [edit] and explain your answer? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - that did it! Could you explain why the terminfo entry requires a single colon while the terminal-override expects a double colon?

Comment: : is a separator in terminal-overrides, :: escapes it.